# How is the principal argument of the root of a complex number found where n is not an integer?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

Consider the complex number `z = 1 − 6i`

I am trying to compute the following:

- The modulus:  `|z|= sqrt(37)`
- The principal argument: `arg(z) = arctan(−6)`

There are four distinct fourth roots to this number. I need to compute the following:

- The modulus of the fourth roots: `|z^(1/4)|= 37^(1/8)`

The principal arguments of the fourth roots of z are, in increasing order:

Smallest argument:

For this I tried to use `arg(z^n) = n arg(z)`

But on wikipedia it states that this can't be used for a non-integer value of n when working with principal arguments. How can I solve this?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Identities

Also how do I get the next largest arguments?

next largest argument =

next largest argument =

largest argument =